How to extract a matrix by using IKernelLink methods and assign into a C# matrix?
I have a question about linking Wolfram Mathematica with C#. The below code is just a simple C# code, and if I could solve the issue in the below code, I will generate the more complex one.
using Wolfram.NetLink;
double [,] matris1=new double[2,2];
double [,] matris2=new double[2,2];
matris1[0,0]=3;
matris2[0,0]=5;

IKernelLink ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();

ml.PutFunction("EvaluatePacket", 1);
ml.PutFunction("Plus", 2);
ml.Put(matris1);
ml.Put(matris2);
ml.EndPacket();
ml.WaitForAnswer();

Console.WriteLine(ml.GetExpr());

Here, I add the two matrices defined in C# using Mathematica's Plus function. Then, using IKernelLink's GetExpr() method, I see the result is correct. However, I don't know how to get the matrix from Mathematica and assign it into a C# matrix. I see that IKernelLink has GetArray() method. However, my result is a matrix, not an array. How could I solve this issue?
I appreciate for your help.
Ahmet
